# Where clause based on a column in an associated model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'd like to conditionally add a `where` clause to my query so that it filters the results by a column in an associated model, of an associated model.

ie: `Application` => `Job` => filter by column of `Company`

currently I can only filter by a column in the `Job` table

These are the associations:

```
Applicant.belongsToMany(Job, {through: Application})
Job.belongsToMany(Applicant, { through: Application });

// Associations so the Application table can be directly queried
Application.belongsTo(Job, { foreignKey: { name: 'jobId' }});
Application.belongsTo(Applicant, { foreignKey: { name: 'applicantId' } });

Company.hasMany(Job, { foreignKey: { name: 'companyId', allowNull: false} });
Job.belongsTo(Company, { foreignKey: { name: 'companyId', allowNull: false} });
```

As above, I'd like to return all the `applications` where the column `name` in the `Company` model is similar to a `searchTerm`

I can currently return only the relevant `applications` where the column `title` in the `Job` model matches, but if I try to filter by a more deeply nested model, like `Company` it doesn't work

Here's how I add a `where` clause to the `options` object to filter by `job.title`:

```
   const options = {
      order: // ...      
      distinct: true,
      attributes //... 
      include: [
        {                               
          model: Job,
          include: [ 
            { 
              model: Company,
              attributes: [ 'id', 'name' ],
              include: [
                {
                  model: Contact,
                  separate: true,
                  include: [{
                    model: Person,
                    attributes: [ 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phone', 'email' ]
                  }]
                }
              ]
            } 
          ]
        },
        {
          model: Applicant,
          include: [ 
            {
              model: Person,
              attributes: [ 'id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'phone', 'createdAt' ]
            } 
          ],
        }
      ];
    }



if(x) options.include[0].where = { title: { [Op.like]: `%${searchTerm}%` } };
const results = Application.findAll(options)
```

This returns **only** the `applications` that have `jobs` with a similar title to the `searchTerm`. Which is what I want, but I suspect that this is a mistake that just *coincidentally* works the way I want it to.

If I try to achieve my real aim - to return **only** the `applications` that have a `job` with a certain `company` name - I add the following to the options object using similar logic:

```
if(x) options.include[0].include[0].where = { name: { [Op.like]: `%${searchTerm}%` } };
```

... but that returns **all** the `applications`, with `null` for the `job` and `company` where the `where` clause doesn't match

Just to clarify, this isn't what I'm after - I'm trying to get only the `applications` where the `company` name is like the `searchTerm`.

Appreciate any help, let me know if I haven't been clear enough!

---

So I *think* I've found the answer: I've been confusing nested `where` clauses with refering to nested columns from the top-level `where` clause using the `$nested.column$` syntax.

So I can do `$nested.nested.column$` and it seems to work:

``` options.where = {'$job.company.name$': { [Op.like]: ``%${searchTerm}%`` }} ```

Although I'm still confused as to why my query filtering by a `Job` column works as expected.